# JQuery Animate (increasing width of img) smoothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So I am trying to create a very slow zooming in and out effect for a banner image

The effect works, but the animation is very very choppy.  Is there anyway to improve the effect to be smoother?  Img is 1000px by default, so a 30% increase in size for the zoomIn function.  At 50000ms its fairly smooth, but for the desired effect (not too distracting to a viewer of the page content) I want it to be 100000-200000ms.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
  $bannerImg = $('img');

  function zoomIn(){
    $bannerImg.animate({
      width: '+=300',
      }, 100000,'linear');
    $bannerImg.promise().done(zoomOut);
  }

  function zoomOut(){
    $bannerImg.animate({
      width: '-=300',
      }, 100000,'linear');
    $bannerImg.promise().done(zoomIn);
  }

  zoomIn();
```

Comment: For browsers that support CSS3 animations, you could use that instead of jQuery `.animate()`.  Can't promise CSS3 animations would be perfect, but they have a better chance of being good than JS animations.  To illustate the choppiness so we can see what you're talking about, please put a working demo into a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add easing to your JS animation fairly easily and it will make everything animate quite a bit smoother. Check out an example here: [jQuery Easing](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations)